# BibLaTex shows only book references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-mla

I'm trying to use a bibliography created using BibDesk in my LaTex document. To this extend I have the following (simplified) document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Pulitzer Prize-winning \autocite{Pulitzer:2017} novel \emph{The Underground Railroad} \autocite{Whitehead:2016}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Then I first run XeLaTeX, then Biber, then XeLaTeX twice again. The problem now is that my bibliography for some reason only displays book references, no article or misc references. Also, there is more whitespace between the references than one expects.

Switching to normal LaTex instead of XeLaTeX didn't fix the problem.

How can I solve this issue?

My bibliography is:

```
@misc{Pulitzer:2017,
    Date-Added = {2017-05-14 12:18:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-05-14 12:27:09 +0000},
    Howpublished = {\url{http://www.pulitzer.org/prize-winners-by-year/2017}},
    Title = {2017 Pulitzer Prizes}}


@book{Whitehead:2016,
    Author = {Whitehead, Colson},
    Date-Added = {2017-05-14 11:51:16 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-05-14 13:45:53 +0000},
    Id = {UBL{\_}ALMA21286889210002711},
    Isbn = {9780385542364},
    Keywords = {PS3573.H4768; PS3573.H4768 U53 2016; Underground Railroad -- Fiction; Fugitive slaves -- United States -- Fiction; United States -- History -- 19th century -- Fiction; 1800-1899; 1800-1899},
    N2 = {"Cora is a slave on a cotton plantation in Georgia. When Caesar, a recent arrival from Virginia, tells her about the Underground Railroad, they decide to take a terrifying risk and escape. Though they manage to find a station and head north, they are being hunted. Their first stop is South Carolina, in a city that initially seems like a haven. But the city's placid surface masks an insidious scheme designed for its black denizens. And even worse: Ridgeway, the relentless slave catcher, is close on their heels. Forced to flee again, Cora embarks on a harrowing flight, state by state, seeking true freedom." --},
    Publisher = {New York : Doubleday},
    Title = {The underground railroad : a novel},
    Ty = {BOOK},
    Year = {2016}}
```

Comment: Please add at least some sample bibliography (best with `filecontents`) to help us help you.

Comment: Yes added the bibliography!

Comment: Don't make a "simplified" document, make a real example, that demonstrates your problem. And check the blg-file for messages.

Comment: Your simplified document is a bit too simple for us to run it properly. Try to make it an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: And your `.bib` file is a bit too verbose. Make it as minimal as possible. It should be enough to just have one `@misc` entry that is not shown to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I changed the TeX and Bibliography code to a working example! My apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `biblatex-mla` style does not support `@misc` entries at the moment.

The style had been unchanged for quite while, then the author released an update at the end of last year to make the style run with newer versions of `biblatex` again and implement 8th edition MLA style (as `style=mla-new`). I'm not sure about the status of `biblatex-mla`at the moment, you can try to contact the maintainer via https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla.

You can try changing the type to `@online` or `@book`. Or use

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{misc}{online}
```