# Why do some of my citations not appear in the reference list?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

Some of my citations show up in the main text, but not in the reference list at the end. I.e. it will say in the text "blabla (Oksanen, 2016)" but the entry for Oksanen will not show up.

Things I have tried:

- Is it the .bib entry? I tried contruting an MWE with the bibentries in question, however the citations worked as expected.
- Is it the way I cite it? I use a custom code snippet `\citeyearpar` that I found here on tex.stackexchange. However in a MWE I constructed, the same command also creates the references I am looking for and the references are not created even when I use the normal `\parencite` command.
- Is it the way I compile? I don't think so because it works in the MWE. I compile using pdfLaTeX -> BibTeX -> pdfLaTeX -> pdfLaTeX

I am really confused, especially because the citations are created in the text. I even use hyperref, but when I click on the citation in the text, it jumps to the blank part of the reference list!

This is the MWEB with the whole preamble from my original document. If I replace `style=mla` with `style=authoryear-comp` it works!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, style=mla]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Report{Oksanen2016,
  author        = {Oksanen, Heikki},
  title         = {Smoothing Asymmetric Shocks vs. Redistribution in the Euro Area: A Simple Proposal for Dealing with Mistrust in the Euro Area},
  abstract      = {The euro area will not have a centralised budget and smoothing of country-specific asymmetric shocks via private financial markets will develop only slowly. Mis},
  date          = {2016-03-23},
}
@Article{Dolls2016,
  author        = {Dolls, Mathias and Fuest, Clemens and Heinemann, Friedrich and Peichl, Andreas},
  title         = {Reconciling Insurance with Market Discipline: a Blueprint for a European Fiscal Union},
  volume        = {62},
  number        = {2},
  pages         = {210--231},
  issn          = {1610-241X},
  date          = {2016-06-01},
  doi           = {10.1093/cesifo/ifw004},
  file          = {Full Text PDF:C\:\\Users\\felix\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\zd4w2j8k.default\\zotero\\storage\\E26WEBI4\\Dolls et al. - 2016 - Reconciling Insurance with Market Discipline a Bl.pdf:application/pdf},
  journaltitle  = {{CESifo} Economic Studies},
  shortjournal  = {{CESifo} Econ Stud},
  shorttitle    = {Reconciling Insurance with Market Discipline},
  url           = {https://academic.oup.com/cesifo/article/62/2/210/1744891/Reconciling-Insurance-with-Market-Discipline-a},
  urldate       = {2017-05-22},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}}}
    {, }
    {}

%\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
this:\citeyearpar{Dolls2016} and that \citeyearpar{Oksanen2016}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, so the next thing after posting this question worked! The culprit was `style=mla` which I found here: (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-mla) . Now I used `style=authoryear-comp` and it shows all citations!

Comment: This is the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369696/35864. `biblatex-mla` does not have a driver for `@report`.  Try `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{report}{book}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the style you use. `biblatex-mla` does not support all standard entry types at the moment. A similar problem was observed in [BibLaTex shows only book references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369696/35864). In your case the problem is that `@report` is not properly supported.

If you want to use all standard entry types, you will have to use a different style.

You can try something like

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{report}{book}
```

or

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{report}{unpublished}
```

but this is just an attempt to save things, it is very likely that this will not yield the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! I will now just use `style=authoryear-comp`, I think it fits my purpose well enough

Comment: @FelixSchleef That is a good alternative if you don't need the exact output of `biblatex-mla`. The standard styles support all entry types listed in the manual and are unlikely to break in future releases.