# Biblatex's footnote style doesn't print the item text

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords = "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \footcite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \footcite{dirac} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

With the following output:
[image]

This all works fine, but I want to change the "Works Cited" title to "Bibliography".

How to do that?

I tried working with the `numeric` option for `biblatex` -

```
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
```

, which led to this result:
[image]

So now I get "Bibliography" as a title, but (almost) no information in the footnote.

Is there an option that I missed in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), so not to define a new macro command in the preamble? If the answer is no, then what is the macro command to be used?

### Edit

With help from moewe, I came to the conclusion that using `[style=verbose]` as an option, together with `\footcite{key}` produces the desired result, viz. printing the cited entry in the footnote of the current page, and no alteration of the `\printbibliography` title to "Works cited" from "Bibliography".

But I have another question, which is how to produce (something almost similar) to the following result:

[image]

That is, in words, cite a bibliography entry in numerical form, make it appear in square parenthesis, AND make it appear at page foot margin. As well, print it in the bibligraphy list when using `\printbibliography`.

If I cite the same work twice or more on the same page, I want it to have the same numerical, no use of "Ibid". If the work is cited on several pages, I don't want any use of "Ibid", nor any use of "see footnote ## on page ##", or something similar. Just have the same numeric it received in the first page it appeared. I also want a corresponding numbering in the bibliography chapter, with "listing per appearance" citations ordering (not alphabetically).

Comment: With `style=numeric,` you get numeric citations (i.e. numbers). If you use `\footcite` you get the citation in a footnote. With numeric citations that ends up just sending a number to the footnote. Not particularly helpful, I admit. Maybe you want to use `style=verbose,`. Or you may want to switch from `\footcite` to `\autocite`, `\parencite` or `\cite`.

Comment: But you don't have to change bibliography styles to change the bibliography heading. `\printbibliography` has a `title` option you can use: `\printbibliography[title=Whatever title you like]` (here you may want to try `\printbibliography[title=\bibname]`). (Note that `style=mla,` has a few issues: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369696/35864, but I'm probably biased against MLA style in general, so don't let me talk you out of using it if you have to or find it pretty.)

Comment: @moewe `[style=verbose]` together with `\footcite{<key>}` works fine. Thanks a lot. Another question: How can I cite a bibliography entry with a `\parencite` command, AND to make it appear at the footnote of the page? I.e., "The journal paper[1]" (where "1" is an entry) and make it appear at the footnote. Should I edit the original question?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you want. Do you just want the footnote number in brackets and normal instead of superscripted? Or do you want a fully-blown numeric style with additional references in the footnote line? If you are not quite sure which you want, ask yourself the following questions: What do you want to happen if you cite the same work multiple times on the same page, what do you want to happen if you cite it several times on different pages? Do you want any numbering in the bibliography? How should the bibliography be ordered: Alphabetically or by appearance citations?

Comment: ... Yes, please edit your question with what you have now and your exact requirements.

Comment: @moewe Thanks so much for your time and notice. I edited the original question.